# How to transform pl sql Json value into a string

Tags: sql, json, string, oracle, plsql

Have a project for work & my SQL skills are improving, but I still struggle with basic stuff every now and then.  I need to get 'fundingCode' to show up as a string rather than a number as it is now.

(i.e. currently the outcome is '"fundingCode": 100001' & I need it to show up as '"fundingCode": "100001"

```
cursor json_index_data (c_org_code VARCHAR2) is 
    select json_object(
            '_dtoName' VALUE 'AeSFndOrganization',
            'companyId' VALUE oa.location_desc,
            'deptId' VALUE OA.DEPT,
            'ocCode' VALUE OA.ORGANIZATION_LEVEL_6,
             nvl('seq', 1) VALUE imi.seq, 
            'fundingCode' VALUE (I.ACCOUNT_INDEX)
    FORMAT JSON)
    as json_row_value
```

Comment: Just gave it a shot, throwing an error unfortunately.  Really appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this was Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a coworker managed to give me a pretty good explanation.  I had previously tried to use concatenation, but I was using bad syntax.  Here is how it was finally accomplished.

```
cursor json_index_data (c_org_code VARCHAR2) is 
    select json_object(
            'multitenantId' VALUE '1',
            '_dtoName' VALUE 'AeSFndOrganization',
            'companyId' VALUE oa.campus_desc,
            'deptId' VALUE OA.DEPT,
            'ocCode' VALUE OA.ORGANIZATION_LEVEL_6,
            nvl('seq', 1) VALUE imi.seq,                 
            'fundingCode' VALUE '"' || I.ACCOUNT_INDEX || '"'
    FORMAT JSON)
    as json_row_value
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you would typically do a `select` statement resulting in JSON would be like this:

```
select json_object(
        key '_dtoName' is 'AeSFndOrganization',
        key 'companyId' is oa.location_desc,
        key 'deptId' is OA.DEPT,
        key 'ocCode' is OA.ORGANIZATION_LEVEL_6,
        key 'seq' is imi.seq, 
        key 'fundingCode' is to_char(I.ACCOUNT_INDEX)
      ) as YOUR_JSON_ALIAS
   from YOUR_TABLENAME;
```

So you define your `key` on the left and your value (with `is`) on the right. I don't think that would act any differently in a cursor if you just put `cursor json_index_data is` in front of it.

If you need to convert a value, use the typical conversion functions like `to_char(the_value)` or `to_number(the_string)`, etc.  That's what I did in the sample query above for:

```
...
key 'fundingCode' is to_char(I.ACCOUNT_INDEX)
...
```